# Clear map of dynamic values in C++

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, stl

I've seen many sites talking about the correct way to implement a d'tor for a class that holds a map.
But not for the case where the values of the map themselves are dynamically allocated.

For example, let `Manager` be a class which hold `map<int, User*>` where `User` is some class which I'll allocate dynamically later.

By the rules of the exercise, it should handle a `registerUser(string name)` function, which creates a new `User` instance and adds it to the map.

Something like:

```
User* registerUser(std::string userName) {
    User* pNewUser = new User(userName);

    // Setting some stuff

    auto ret = users.insert(std::pair<int, User*>(pNewUser->id, pNewUser));

    // Finishing and returning a pointer to the new allocated User
}
```

AND TO THE QUESTION ITSELF:

Should the d'tor do something special beyond `users.clear()`?

Will the memory be freed successfully or shall I iterate over the elements and delete them?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: the destructor should do "something special" but it needs not call `users.clear()`. Can you use smart pointers?

Comment: Starting with the simplest principle: If you `new` something, you have to `delete` it later. `registerUser` calls `new`, so you have to figure out who's responsible for calling the `delete`. Right now it looks like that's the `Manager` itself.

But it's possible to represent this ownership model without using raw pointers and without calling `new` or `delete` at all, as the previous commenter alluded to. You could have a `map<int, std::unique_ptr<User>>` which would mean that the Manager is solely responsible for them. It would then allow you to greatly simplify your destructor.

Comment: I can't use smart pointers, unfortunately, but it's good to know that I need to use `delete` and my suspicions were correct. Thank you! :)

Comment: ok, no smart pointers, but why dynamically allocate the users manually? Why do you not use a `std::map<int,User>` ?

Comment: The most correct code would be not have a pointer at all, and instead have a map of `<int, User>`. As a  general rule, owning pointers are appropriate in C++ when run-time polymorphism is involved, and rarely in any other case.

Comment: By the exercise, I need to use a map with a pointer to `User`.

Comment: Also be sure to make a copy constructor that properly copies, too.  The default one will copy the map and the pointers will alias the same objects as the source, leaving them invalid if the source object is destroyed (once you fix your dtor to delete them!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use pointers when you do not have to. The `std::map` already manages the lifetime of its elements for you:

```
struct User {
    std::string name;
    int id;
    static int id_counter;
    User(const std::string& name) : name(name),id(id_counter++) {}
};

struct manager {
    std::map<int,User> users;

    User& registerUser(std::string userName) {                    
        User u(userName);
        auto ret = users.emplace(u.id,u);
        return ret.first->second;
    }
};
```

If you are forced to use a `std::map<int,User*>` because of weird unrealistic exercise requirements (or because the map is supposed to hold polymorphic objects) and you cannot use smart pointers then you need to `delete` what you `new`ed. The map only manages its elements, not what they might point to:

```
struct manager {
    std::map<int,User*> users;

    User& registerUser(std::string userName) {               
        User* u = new User(userName);
        auto ret = users.emplace(u->id,u);
        return *(ret.first->second);
    }

    ~manager() {
        for (const auto& user : users){
            delete user.second;
        }
    }

    // the compiler generated assignment and copy would not do the right thing
    manager(const manager&) = delete;
    manager& operator=(const manager&) = delete;
};
```

Not sure where you read about holding a `map` as member and needing to call `clear()`. That is non-sense. The `map` has a destructor that is called automatically and the map does already clean up after itself.

Last but not least, you need to read about the rule of 3 ([What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)), because a destructor alone is not sufficient to correctly manage raw pointers as members. As mentioned in a comment, when you copy the `manager` via the compiler generated copy constructor or assignment, bad things will happen. Note that this isnt the case with the first version above. When possible you should try to follow the rule of 0 (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three scroll down).

Answer (score 1):

**Should the d'tor do something special beyond `users.clear()`?**

In general that depends on how your code handles ownership of heap allocated objects; any time you call a constructor by `new` (aka allocate on the heap) you should be aware of wich component in your code takes ownership over the newly created object and in consequence is responsible for deletion of the object.

For this specific toyproblem your `Manager` class should also handle the deletion of the object by iterating over all elements in your favourite way and calling `delete`. Be aware some other component could still hold onto one of these `User`-pointers wich will cause a crash by accessing **invalid memory** in the best case and running fine until it shipped in the worst case (or starting a nuclear war, since this is in the scope of **undefined behaviour**). The state of the art solution is using some kind of smart pointer.

Of course as [463035818_is_not_a_number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68595542/7136013) put it so nicely in his answer you don't need to call `users.clear()`. Since the `map` will be deleted automagically since it is a statically allocated variable **(but not necessarily the contents of the `map`)**.